# Legal Status of Selective Service Records Regarding Conscientious Objection

Tags: united-states, privacy, foia

What is the legal status of conscientious objector forms in the US draft? Specifically, **are records regarding specific individuals' conscientious objector applications subject to FOIA**, and **are they protected by some US privacy law**?

Comment: I assume you’re talking about forms from Vietnam and before, right? (currently, since there is no active draft, there *isn’t* a conscientious objection system)

Comment: Vietnam is preferable, though answers which apply to earlier records are acceptable.